# Google maps : Is it possible to draw a polygon and retrieve all street names within it?

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps' API v3, is it possible to draw a polygon on a Google maps and get a list of all the street names that fall within that polygon?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? I can't see an explicit method for that, but I can think of some terrible hacks. Compute a fine grid (2m x 2m) of points over the polygon, reverse-geocode, get the street name from the response. Or use OpenStreetMap instead, and the Overpass API which (I think) can do this.

Comment: you can send the lat,lng of your polygon as directions like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=wynkoop+st,+denver&destination=stout+st,+denver&sensor=false

Answer (score 5):

So I used the solution (OpenStreetMap) from @Spacedman:

1. Download the .pbf for your country https://download.geofabrik.de
2. Download the polygon file for the desired municipality from https://github.com/JamesChevalier/cities or **create your polygon file (.poly) here** : http://share.mapbbcode.org/
3. Download lasted version from Osmosis https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Latest_stable_version
4. Do this:

   osmosis --read-pbf-fast you_file_country-latest.osm.pbf file="your_file_country-latest.osm.pbf" --bounding-polygon file="your_municipality_polygon.poly" --write-xml file="your_file_out.osm"

[image]
5. In the .osm file, you obtain all the street names, to extract the names use the option (regex) of notepad++

[image]

It's complex but it works, but I still have to find a way to do it directly from Google API

Comment: I think you should take a look at Overpass API, the following query will return all highway=* with a name in your bounding box: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/AD5 ... Polygon selection would also be possible.

Comment: Please check my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/413760/194536) if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

[Sandra's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125787/sandra) solution put me into the right direction and helped me a lot. However, I am convinced the way how she "*parses*" the output file is not correct and the regular expression doesn't cover all streets - at least in Spain as a street can start with *Calle* and this kind of streets don't have the `addr:street` key.

This is a Linux solution which bases on Sandra's answer:

```
bin/osmosis -q ... --bp file="My.poly" \
            --tf accept-nodes way=* --wk keyList=highway --wx file=- \
    | sed -e 's/[ ]*<nd [^>]*>//g' \
    | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' \
    | perl -lne 'print $1 if /k="name" v="(.+)"/' \
    | sort \
    | uniq
```

***What happens:***

1. Get only the `way` nodes which contain the `highway` key.
2. Remove the `<nd..>` elements. Here I refer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413747/remove-some-elements-from-way) regarding removing it.
3. Remove empty lines.
4. Run `perl` in order to get the street name from the element.
5. Sort the result.
6. Remove duplicates which can be, when for example the street is a one-way and has multiple entries.