# Remove some elements from way

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmfilter

I am passing osmosis with along the base parameters this additional option: `--tf accept-nodes way=*`

With this I could filter only the `<way...>` nodes and the result is something like this:

```
  <way id="96036111" version="5" timestamp="2018-03-03T02:44:07Z" uid="0" user="">
    <nd ref="1112713500"/>
    <nd ref="1112712866"/>
    <nd ref="1112712764"/>
    <nd ref="1039249814"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Avenida del Prado"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  </way>
```

I don't figure out how to remove the `<nd>` elements and keep only `<tag ...>`, so the result would be:

```
  <way id="96036111" version="5" timestamp="2018-03-03T02:44:07Z" uid="0" user="">
    <tag k="name" v="Avenida del Prado"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  </way>
```

***My question:***
How can I remove the `<nd..>` elements from the result?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `osmosis` under Linux, so `sed` can be used to remove these elements. Even this solution works, I am curious if it can be done directly with `osmosis`.

```
bin/osmosis -q ... --tf accept-nodes way=* --wk keyList=name --wx file=- \
    | sed -e 's/[ ]*<nd [^>]*>//g' \
    | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' > MyFile.osm
```

The 1st `sed` removes the `<nd...>` elements.
The 2nd `sed` just removes the empty lines